# how to get the Material of group in sketchup?

Tags: c, sdk, sketchup

I have done iterating through the entities in a group, getting all the faces, and then getting the material of each face. However, if the material belongs to a group, there is no material on the face. How do I get the material of the group in this case? I use the C API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A face can have a front material (and back material) and still be in a group with a group material.  In fact it's very common.  In that case, the face material takes precedence over the group material.

```
SU_RESULT SUFaceGetFrontMaterial(SUFaceRef face, SUMaterialRef* material);
SU_RESULT SUFaceGetBackMaterial(SUFaceRef face, SUMaterialRef* material);
```

In addition, there is a much more direct way to get the material of a group.

```
SUDrawingElementRef draw = SUGroupToDrawingElement(group);
SUMaterialRef material = SU_INVALID;
SUDrawingElementGetMaterial(draw, &material);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, convert the group object into an entity, and then get the texture of the entity through the `SUTextureWriterLoadEntity` method。

```
SUGroupRef _group；
long EntityTextureId = 0;    
SUTextureWriterLoadEntity(m_uvWrite, SUGroupToEntity(_group), &EntityTextureId)
```